# std::map три аргумента, в каких случаях такое может быть?

Tags: c++, map

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что могут означать три аргумента в ассоциативном контейнере и в каких случаях такое возможно?. Обычно их два - ключ и значение, но я нашел в рабочем коде три:

```
typedef std::map<Tree::type_key, DestFunc, Tree::compare_key> dest_map;
```

Comment: А не функция ли это сравнения?

Answer (score 5):

Третий аргумент — это *компаратор*, функциональный объект (или функция, как частный случай), позволяющий узнавать порядок любых двух ключей относительно друг друга.

Это нужно потому, что `std::map` — это **упорядоченный** список пар «ключ — значение». Вот компаратор и позволяет определить правила этого упорядочивания.

При этом упорядочивание не только используется для ускорения поиска записей, но и определяет, в каком порядке эти записи будут выдаваться при переборе элементов списка.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то у стандартного шаблона-контейнера `std::map` даже не три, а *четыре* шаблонных параметра: ключ, данные, компаратор и аллокатор.

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

Все четыре параметра - *типы*. Фактические же *объекты* этих типов создаются во время выполнения. Объекты типа "ключ" и "данные" вы передаете сами при создании элементов, а фактические объекты компаратора и аллокатора создаются при конструировании контейнера.

Вы ранее могли пользоваться данным контейнером указывая два шаблонных аргумента только потому, что у третьего и четвертого аргумента, как вы видите выше, есть аргументы по умолчанию  - `std::less` и `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Data>` соответственно.

В данном случае вы смотрите на пример, в котором указан другой тип компаратора.

Comment: `умолчательные значения` бр-р-р ...