# Шаблоны переменных в C++14

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Изучая новый стандарт C++, натолкнулся на нововведение «**шаблоны переменных**»

Синтаксис у шаблона следующий:

```
template < typename T >
constexpr T value = T(1234);
```

О применении шаблона написано:

> Данная возможность позволяет создавать и использовать `constexpr` шаблоны переменных, для более удобного сочетания с шаблонными алгоритмами.

Не вполне понимаю, как такая переменная будет использоваться в *шаблонном алгоритме*. Не могли бы Вы привести несколько примеров использования этого механизма? Также не понимаю, почему нельзя такое шаблонное `constexpr` выражение заменить *нешаблонным*, ведь значение мы указываем явно, соответственно, и тип можем написать (вывести) явно.

Comment: `значение мы указываем явно` — не так. Явно указывается параметр конструктора, а дальнейшие действия с ним зависят от типа `T`. Если это встроенный числовой тип, то да, произойдёт расширение разрядности и число останется числом. Но если в качестве `T` у нас какой-нибудь класс, то всё становится куда интереснее.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

В стандарте есть [пример](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#3):

```
template<class T>
constexpr T pi = T(3.1415926535897932385L);

template<class T>
T circular_area(T r) {
  return pi<T> * r * r;
}
```

Здесь шаблон переменной позволяет получить константу нужного размера - float/double/etc.

---

Другое популярное применение - это замена `is_some<T>::value` на `is_some_v<T>`, например

```
template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;  // C++17
```

Answer (score 7):

Тут можно заметить, что при объявлении шаблона переменной тип этой переменной совсем не обязан совпадать с параметром шаблона или вообще быть как-то связан с параметром(-ами) шаблона. Большинство тривиальных примеров шаблонов переменных обычно дают переменной тот же самый тип, что использовался в параметре шаблона, что может создать ложное впечатление, как будто это требуется. На самом деле шаблонная переменная может иметь любой тип.

Например, пользуясь примером с площадью окружности, вы можете принять решение использовать "базовое" определение константы `PI` с конкретным типом `double`

```
template<class T> constexpr double PI = 3.141592653589793;
```

а затем, пользуясь явной специализацией, добавить специализированные определения для отдельных плавающих типов

```
template<> constexpr float PI<float> = 3.1415927;
template<> constexpr long double PI<long double> = 3.141592653589793238L;
```

После этого можно будет реализовать "единую" шаблонную функцию вычисления площади окружности

```
template<class T> T circle_area(T r) 
{
  return PI<T> * r * r;
}
```

которая будет, например, работать и с целочисленными типами

```
int area = circle_area(10);
```

Для целочисленных типов в качестве константы `PI` будет браться  вариант "по умолчанию" с типом `double`, а для плавающих типов будут использоваться специализированные значения этой константы.

Вариант реализации этой функции из ответа @Abyx, как вы наверное заметили, тоже будет "работать" с целочисленными типами. Но в том варианте константа Пи для целочисленных типов получит целочисленное значение `3`, что не всегда желательно.

---

Также можно добавить, что возможность включения статических членов-данных в шаблоны классов существовала в языке С++ с самого начала стандартизованных времен, т.е. в С++98. Это позволяло реализовывать "шаблоны переменных" уже тогда, пользуясь фактически той же самой техникой, которая в С++98 применялась для ["шаблонных typedef"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm), т.е. через помещение типов или переменных в "обертку" шаблонного класса. В частности, вышеприведенный пример может быть реализован на классическом С++98 как

```
template <typename T> struct PI { static const double value; };
template <typename T> const double PI<T>::value = 3.141592653589793;

template <> struct PI<float> { static const float value; };
const float PI<float>::value = 3.1415927;

template <> struct PI<long double> { static const long double value; };
const long double PI<long double>::value = 3.141592653589793238L;

template<class T> T circle_area(T r) 
{
  return PI<T>::value * r * r;
}
```

Принимая это во внимание, можно сказать, что шаблонные переменные не являются каким-то фундаментально новым свойством С++14. Они (выражаясь нестрого) являются просто "синтаксическим сахаром", более компактным и элегантным вариантом синтаксиса для записи вышеприведенного С++98 варианта реализации. Ситуация аналогична введенной в С++11 возможность объявления шаблонных typedef (через `using`), которая тоже может быть названа "синтаксическим сахаром" над хорошо известной С++98 техникой "шаблонного typedef".

Comment: [Снова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653977/stdmap-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c/653990#comment937250_653990) этот ["умолчательный"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).