# Какие бывают виды шаблонов (templates) в C++?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В `c++` есть шаблоны классов (сюда же структур) и функций. Я узнал, что это не все виды шаблонов (templates), но нигде не могу найти остальные. По запросу

> шаблоны c++

Как раз выдает те самые шаблоны классов и функций. Есть еще шаблоны функций-членов класса, но это, мне кажется, не все виды шаблонов. Какие еще виды шаблонов бывают? Можно полный список?

Comment: Например - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737944/195342

Comment: еще есть шаблоны алиасы и шаблоны значений. концепты можно тоже считать шаблонами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под шаблоном (template) понимают:

> 1. Шаблон класса (class template),
> 2. Шаблон функции (function template),
> 3. Шаблонный псевдоним типа (alias template),
> 4. Шаблон переменной (variable template),
> 5. концепт (concept).

Под шаблонным объектом (templated entity) понимают:

> 1. Любой шаблон;
> 2. Всякий член (member) шаблонного объекта;
> 3. Enumerator (член перечисления (enum), не знаю устоявшегося русского названия)
> 4. Перечисления, которое является шаблонным объектом;
> 5. Любой объект (entity), определённый или созданный внутри шаблонного объекта;
> 6. Тип замыкания (closure type) лямбда-выражения в объявлении шаблонного объекта.

[Источник](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre)